# Override DependencyInjection/configuration.php of third party bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony-sonata

I am using `sonataNofificationBundle`, they have provided four backends. I have the custom requirement so want to add one more backend. They have backend configurations in

```
DependencyInjection/configuration.php,
DependencyInjection/SonataNotificationExtension.php, 
Resources/Config/backend.xml.
```

Instead of making changes in `sonataNotificationBundle` files, I want to create bundle which override these files to create one more backend.

Does Symfony2 allow to override DependencyInjection configuration files ? Is there any way to achieve the same goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to take a quick glance at [the official doc about overriding bundles configurations?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own backend, you can create the backend service inside a dedicated bundle. Then inside the Sonata Notification configuration section (http://www.sonata-project.org/bundles/notification/2-1/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html) you can provide the service id of your backend.

That's it!